# Printing decimal numbers

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, mathematics

I made simple sketch that generates three random numbers and then calculates the average of these three random numbers.

It divides the total by 3 and then displays that average number with `serial.println`.

Sometimes the generated average number can be decimal (for example 261,333333 or 124,33333).

Interestingly, the serial print doesn't print in decimal format **124,33333**
it prints just integer **124**.

How do I print the value in decimal?

Comment: Please show your code. Without that we can't help you.

Comment: Please edit your question, and post your code. How have you declared your variables, as `int`s or `float`s?

Answer (score 3):

In languages such as C or C++ there is a distinction between integer types and floating-point types. You see, computers work using **bits**. A bit is either **0** or **1**. A bit obviously lack in both range and precision, so we combine multiple bits in order to improve.

## Integral Types

A **byte** is a group of 8 bits. In C, the type used is either

```
uint8_t x; // Values from 0 to 255.
int8_t  x; // Values from -128 to 127
char    x; // Values from the ASCII character set (still -128 to 127)
```

On Ardiuno Uno, an **int** is a group of 16 bits:

```
uint16_t c; // Values from 0 to 2^16-1 = 65535, synonym: unsigned int (Arduino)
int16_t  c; // Values from -32768 to 32767,     synonym: int (Arduino)
```

A **long** is a group of 32 bits:

```
uint32_t v; // Values from 0 to 2^32-1 = 4,294,967,295 = 4 GiB (unsigned long)
int32_t  v; // Values from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 (long)
```

There is also usually support for 64-bit numbers, but we try not to use them in Arduino code. The reason is that most Arduino MCUs use **8-bit** registers, so 64-bit operations such as "add", "sub", etc. would be very slow.

**Note**: Different architectures use different numbers of bits for these types. In order to be compatible with other architectures, use `int32_t` etc. to be sure.

### Literals and Casts

Oftentimes, the compiler can not see what type a literal value is supposed to be. In C, the compiler picks a default which is usually larger than you would like. For this reason, it is useful to know how to specify a literal exactly with the type:

```
 ((uint8_t)200)   // Casting 200 to an unsigned 8-bit integer
 ((char)65)       // Making the ASCII letter 'A'
 ((int32_t)42)    // Force 32 as a signed 32-bit integer (long)
 42L              // The 'L' suffix does the same as above
```

### Division and Remainder

A common cause of problems when programming in C is the division operator `/`. If the operands are both integer types, the result will also be an integer. So `1/3` is in fact `0`. You can get the remainder of the division using the modulus operation `%`. For instance:

```
void show_division(int n, int d)
{
    Serial.print("The division: ");
    Serial.print(n);
    Serial.print(" / ");
    Serial.print(d);
    Serial.print(" equals ");
    Serial.print(n / d);
    Serial.print(" with a remainder ");
    Serial.println(n % d);
}
```

## Floating-point Types

All of the above types are integrals, so they do not support any fractional value. Therefore C defines **two** different floating-point types: **float** and **double**. The former is a 32-bit value and the latter is a 64-bit value. The way it works is that the bits are split in 3:

- A single bit is used for the **sign**.
- A certain number of bits represent the fractional part, the **mantissa**.
- The rest of the bits are used for the **exponent**.

As an example, the 32-bit float value representation for 1.25 is

```
seeeeeee_emmmmmmm_mmmmmmmm_mmmmmmmm = s * 2^(e-127) * (1.m...)_2
00111111_10100000_00000000_00000000 = (+1) * 2^(127-127) * (1.0100)_2
// Note: Binary 1.01 equals 1.25 in decimal
```

### For performance, use the `f` suffix

Although 64-bit doubles are very accurate, the resulting code will run much slower. I, therefore, recommend using 32-bit floats instead. It is useful to know that you can tack on an `f` after the floating-point literal:

```
(a + b + c) / 3.0f; // Make sure to divide using 32-bit operations.
```

If `a`, `b` and `c` above are integer types, the additions will also be integer additions. When the compiler sees an `int` divided by a `float`, it will convert the `int` to a `float`, and then perform a float division. This is slow, but certainly faster than a double division.

The compiler is smart, but it doesn't hurt to help it. There is only a very small precision loss in converting this to a float multiplication:

```
(a + b + c) * (1.0f / 3.0f);
```

The compiler will pre-calculate `(1.0f / 3.0f)`, so you get a much faster floating-point multiplication (in addition to the `int` to `float` cast).

**Note**: Arduino Uno defaults all floating point literals to 32-bit, and `double` is the same as `float`. Therefore, the `f` suffix is strictly not needed. It is still good practice to add these for compatibility with other architectures.

Comment: Your answer would be correct on many CPU architectures. However, the question is tagged “arduino-uno”, which implies an AVR architecture, and there are three specific details in your answer which are _incorrect_ in this specific architecture: 1) chars are signed. 2) ints are 16 bits, not 32. 3) doubles are 32 bits, just like floats. Then, obviously, the `f` suffix has no effect at all. Could you please fix your answer?

Comment: Thanks, I will. Note though, that I do mention that in the `int` section.

Answer (score 2):

In the C family of languages, if you divide an integer by another
integer, the compiler interprets the division operator (`/`) as an
*integer division*, i.e. you get the integer part of the quotient. Thus,

```c
(first_int + second_int + third_int) / 3
```

is an integer.

If either operand is a floating point number, then the other one is
implicitly converted to floating point, and you get a floating point
division. Thus

```
(first_int + second_int + third_int) / 3.0
```

is a floating point number, and the result you expect.

Comment: shouldn't one of your variables in the second code line be a float? All ints divided will still be an int

Comment: `3.0`, as any constant having a decimal point, is a floating point number. As opposed to `3`, which is an int.